# python how to stop a function without using keyboard from other python script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

Hi guys i dont know if this is possible because i lack knowledge, i want to stop a function( def home(): ) running with a ball tracking and uses camera without using keyboard, because i will dont have the acces to the keyboard when it runs. i have another script that is been calling that function when i clicked a button in my android app, and it doesn't stop when i call another funtion

here is the script that calls that function

```
import apptopi     <<=====this is the imported script which has the function 
from socket import *
from time import ctime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

Servomotor.setup()

ctrCmd = ['Track','StopTracking']

HOST = ''
PORT = 21567
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)

tcpSerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpSerSock.bind(ADDR)
tcpSerSock.listen(5)

while True:
        print 'Waiting for connection'
        tcpCliSock,addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
        print '...connected from :', addr
        try:
                while True:
                        data = ''
                        data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZE)
                        if not data:
                                break
                        if data == ctrCmd[0]:          <== calls the function Track
                                apptopi.Track()
                                print 'Tracking '
                        if data == ctrCmd[1]:          <== in this i want to stop the track function
                                apptopi.Stop()
                                print 'Stop Tracking '
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                Servomotor.close()
                GPIO.cleanup()
tcpSerSock.close();
```

here is the code that i want to stop when i click a button from my app

```
def Track():
    for image in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
      #grab the raw NumPy array representing the image, then initialize the timestamp and occupied/unoccupied text
      frame = image.array
      frame=cv2.flip(frame,1)
      global centre_x
      global centre_y
      centre_x=0.
      centre_y=0.
      hsv1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
      mask_red=segment_colour(frame)      #masking red the frame
      loct,area=find_blob(mask_red)
      x,y,w,h=loct

      #distance coming from front ultrasonic sensor
      distanceC = sonar(GPIO_TRIGGER2,GPIO_ECHO2)
      #distance coming from right ultrasonic sensor
      distanceR = sonar(GPIO_TRIGGER3,GPIO_ECHO3)
      #distance coming from left ultrasonic sensor
      distanceL = sonar(GPIO_TRIGGER1,GPIO_ECHO1)

      if (w*h) < 10:
            found=0
      else:
            found=1
            simg2 = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), 255,2)
            centre_x=x+((w)/2)
            centre_y=y+((h)/2)
            cv2.circle(frame,(int(centre_x),int(centre_y)),3,(0,110,255),-1)
            centre_x-=80
            centre_y=6--centre_y
            print centre_x,centre_y
      initial=400
      flag=0
      GPIO.output(LED_PIN,GPIO.LOW)          
      if(found==0):
            #if the ball is not found and the last time it sees ball in which direction, it will start to rotate in that direction
            if flag==0:
                  rightturn()
                  time.sleep(0.05)
            else:
                  leftturn()
                  time.sleep(0.05)
            stop()
            time.sleep(0.0125)

      elif(found==1):
            if(area<initial):
                  if(distanceC<10):
                        #if ball is too far but it detects something in front of it,then it avoid it and reaches the ball.
                        if distanceR>=8:
                              rightturn()
                              time.sleep(0.00625)
                              stop()
                              time.sleep(0.0125)
                              forward()
                              time.sleep(0.00625)
                              stop()
                              time.sleep(0.0125)
                              #while found==0:
                              leftturn()
                              time.sleep(0.00625)
                        elif distanceL>=8:
                              leftturn()
                              time.sleep(0.00625)
                              stop()
                              time.sleep(0.0125)
                              forward()
                              time.sleep(0.00625)
                              stop()
                              time.sleep(0.0125)
                              rightturn()
                              time.sleep(0.00625)
                              stop()
                              time.sleep(0.0125)
                        else:
                              stop()
                              time.sleep(0.01)
                  else:
                        #otherwise it move forward
                        forward()
                        time.sleep(0.00625)
            elif(area>=initial):
                  initial2=6700
                  if(area<initial2):
                        if(distanceC>10):
                              #it brings coordinates of ball to center of camera's imaginary axis.
                              if(centre_x<=-20 or centre_x>=20):
                                    if(centre_x<0):
                                          flag=0
                                          rightturn()
                                          time.sleep(0.025)
                                    elif(centre_x>0):
                                          flag=1
                                          leftturn()
                                          time.sleep(0.025)
                              forward()
                              time.sleep(0.00003125)
                              stop()
                              time.sleep(0.00625)
                        else:
                              stop()
                              time.sleep(0.01)

                  else:
                        #if it founds the ball and it is too close it lights up the led.
                        GPIO.output(LED_PIN,GPIO.HIGH)
                        time.sleep(0.1)
                        stop()
                        time.sleep(0.1)
      #cv2.imshow("draw",frame)    
      rawCapture.truncate(0)  # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame

      if(cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q')):  <<== i will be dont have the acces to keyboard when it runs and i want to change it
            break

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Really need your help guys our defense is 3 days from now , i would be very grateful, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Convert the Track function to a thread and then start the thread where you want to start the Track function and the stop the thread where you want to stop it.